# opencv stereo calibration result

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

As if i have two web camera,mark as `cam1`,`cam2`.And i want to calibrate them to get the transformation between them.

I used `cv::stereoCalibrate()` to calibrate.

After i got the transformation from `cam1` to `cam2`,mark as `R`,`T`.I want to check the accuracy of the calibration result.

So i used `cam1` and `cam2` to take a picture of a chessboard,mark as `pic1`,`pic2`.I got the `cam1`'s extrinsic parameters by `cv::solvePnP()`.And i drew the `cam1`'s world coordinate system by `cv::projectPoints()` in `pic1`.

Then,i think the `cam2`'s rotation matrix=`cam1`'s rotation matrix * `R`.And the `cam2`'s translation matrix=`cam1`'s translation matrix + `T`.

I calculated the `cam2`'s extrinsic parameters by the above thought.And also drew the `cam2`'s world coordinate system by `cv::projectPoints()` in `pic2`.

But the `pic2`'s origin was not in right position.

Here is part of the code i used.

```
void check_res(const vector<string> &imgs_nm,const Mat &R,const Mat &T,const Mat &cam_c,const Mat &cam_h,const Mat &dist_c,const Mat &dist_h)
{
    int imgs_cnt=imgs_nm.size()/2;
    vector<Point3f> obj_pts;
    for(int i=0;i<boardDimensions.height;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<boardDimensions.width;j++)
            obj_pts.push_back(Point3f(i*CHESS_LEN,j*CHESS_LEN,0.f));
    for(int i=0;i<imgs_cnt;i++)
    {
        vector<Point2f> c_cners,h_cners;
        Mat imgc_gray,imgh_gray;
        Mat imgc=imread(imgs_nm[i*2],1);
        Mat imgc_rz=imgc.clone();

        bool c_found,h_found;
        c_found=HasChessBoard(imgc_rz,imgc_gray,c_cners);
        if(c_found)
            cv::cornerSubPix(imgc_gray, c_cners, cv::Size(11, 11), cv::Size(-1, -1),cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
        Mat imgh=imread(imgs_nm[i*2+1],1);
        h_found=HasChessBoard(imgh,imgh_gray,h_cners);
        if(h_found)
            cv::cornerSubPix(imgh_gray, h_cners, cv::Size(11, 11), cv::Size(-1, -1),cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
        Mat rvec_c,rvec_h,tvec_c,tvec_h;
        cv::solvePnP(obj_pts,c_cners,cam_c,dist_c,rvec_c,tvec_c);
        cv::solvePnP(obj_pts,h_cners,cam_h,dist_h,rvec_h,tvec_h);
        Mat rrvec_c,rrvec_h;
        cv::Rodrigues(rvec_c,rrvec_c);
        cv::Rodrigues(rvec_h,rrvec_h);
        Mat r1=rrvec_c*R;
        Mat t1=tvec_c+T;

        Mat img1=imgh.clone();
        draw_chess(imgh,rrvec_h,tvec_h,cam_h,dist_h);
        imshow("pic1",imgh);
        draw_chess(img1,r1,t1,cam_h,dist_h);
        imshow("pic2",img1);


        char resc=waitKey(0);
        if(resc=='q')
            exit(1);

    }
}
```

And below is the result i tested by using the sample in `opencv`.

[image]

I don't think it was low calibration accuracy,because i use the `opencv`'s   sample and the `cv::stereoCalibrate()` return rms less than 1 pixel.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas are:

- pose for the camera 1 (in homogeneous matrix):

[image: formula1]

- homogeneous transformation from camera 1 to camera 2:

[image: formula2]

- pose for camera 2:

[image: formula3]

Comment: I've tried it with your answer.The result shows that it was almost in same position.Thanks a lot!

Comment: But i though `cam2`'s pose=`cam1`'s pose * `[ R | T ]`.Mark `cam1`'s pose=`[ R1 | T1  ]`,`cam2`'s pose=`[ R2 | T2 ]`,tranformation between them=`[ R | T ]`.The world coordinate system's origin * `[ R1 | T1 ]`=`cam1`'s camera coordinate system's origin.Then we multiply it with `[ R | T ]`,so we transform the point to the `cam2`'s coordinate system's origin.I wonder to know where i was wrong,please tell me.

Comment: Point expressed in the camera1 frame: `X_c1 = (R_c1 | T_c1) . X_w` ; Transformation between the two cameras: `X_c2 = (c2_R_c1 | c2_T_c1) . X_c1` ; Point expressed in the camera2 frame: `X_c2 = (c2_R_c1 | c2_T_c1) . (R_c1 | T_c1) . X_w` The rest is matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

For checking the accuracy of your stereo calibration, I would consider a different approach:

1. Use the function `stereoRectify` to get the rectification transformation for the camera. Use the translation and rotation matrices you got from `stereoCalibrate`.
2. Perform `initUndistortRectifyMap` once for each camera. Use
3. Use the results you got to `remap` the images from both cameras.

If your calibration went well, the output images should be rectified and undistorted.

Comment: Yes,you're right.The `opencv`'s sample code is using the same approach as yours.And the R,T between the two cameras was got from the approach you mentioned.But the result images show that i may made some mistakes that i don't know.

Comment: Sorry, then I must have misunderstood your question. Glad to see the other aproach works though!

Comment: Never mind,the answer might give some help to others.Thanks for your sharing!